# are nested square brackets possible?

Tags: c, syntax

I'm facing k&r exercise 1.24, that states: "Write a program to check a C program for rudimentary syntax errors like unmatched parentheses, brackets and braces".

I'm not sure about how to deal with square brackets.

Are nested square brackets possible in ANSI C syntax ?
I haven't yet seen them so far, but I'm only at Chapter 1.

Comment: Yes, they are possible: `a[b[i]]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure it is possible, access an array, in the place denoted in a second array. `a[b[i]]`

It is often used for [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort), where your buckets is a second array, and each bucket is an element in this array.

Comment: Thanks! When I ask a question on stackoverflow I always learn something more than what I expect, even when my question is somehow trivial!

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible:

```
int index[] = {0,3,1,3};
int data[] = {9,10,22,34};

data[index[0]] = 0;
data[index[1]] = 1;
data[index[2]] = 2;
data[index[3]] = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing an array in an array is possible

```
x[y[0]] //valid;
```

But not for syntax within an array

```
x[[0]] //invalid;
```